# Theorem on convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

**Theorem.**  *If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely and $(b_n)$ is a bounded sequence, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges absolutely.*

***Proof.***  Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely and $(b_n)$ is a bounded sequence. The second hypothesis means that there exists at least one positive real number $M$ such that
\begin{align*}
&0\leq |b_n| < M,\hspace{0.3 in} \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\\
\tag{1}
&\implies 0\leq |a_nb_n|\leq M|a_n|,\hspace{0.3 in} \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{align*}
The first hypothesis implies that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M|a_n|$ converges, which, togheter with the claim at $(1)$, implies, by the Comparision criteria, that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_nb_n|$ converges, which means that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges absolutely. $\blacksquare$

Is my proof correct? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Yes it is. However, a little more formalism may improve your proof.

Comment: can you give an example please?